# How do you handle onChange() of @EnvironmentObject in an SKScene, and not break the scene rendering?

Tags: swiftui, sprite-kit, skscene

In the test code below the blue ellipse is drawn, but the red ellipse is not drawn.  Is there a way to handle the onChange and call a drawing function in a SpriteKit scene? (The print statement inside handleDataChange() does print to the console.)

The gameEnvData is being changed in a separate scene.

```
import SwiftUI
import SpriteKit

struct NextPieceView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var gameEnvData: GameData
    
    var scene: NextPieceScene {
        let scene = NextPieceScene()
        scene.size = CGSize(width: 200, height: 100)
        scene.gameData = gameEnvData
        return scene
    }
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .onChange(of: gameEnvData.pieceCount, perform: { _ in
            scene.handleDataChange()
        })
    }
}
```

```
import SpriteKit
class NextPieceScene: SKScene {
    var gameData: GameData = GameData()
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        drawTestShape(position: CGPoint(x: 25, y: 50), color: .blue) // this works
    }
    
    func handleDataChange() {
        print("handleDataChange called")
        drawTestShape(position: CGPoint(x: 75, y: 50), color: .red) // does not draw
    }
    
    func drawTestShape(position: CGPoint, color: UIColor) {
        let shapeNode = SKShapeNode(ellipseOf: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        shapeNode.fillColor = color
        shapeNode.position = position
        addChild(shapeNode)
    }
}
```

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the `addChild` line, does the number of children increase when you add the red shape? I suspect your problem is caused by the `scene` property in the view being a regular var. SwiftUI views get destroyed and recreated when anything changes in the view. When the view is recreated, so is the `scene` variable. You should use the `@State` property wrapper for `scene` to keep the same scene instance every time there's a change in the view. Example: `@State var scene: NextPieceScene`

Comment: You are correct, thanks!  The count of children was not increasing.  By wrapping the scene in @State as you suggested, it is drawing the test shapes, and the children count is increasing.  I couldn’t use the wrapper on a computed property so I had to slightly change the way I declared the scene.

Answer (score 0):

Fixes:

1. Used the @State wrapper when declaring the scene
2. The scene could no longer be a computed property, due to wrapper
3. Now passing the @EO gameEnvData in via the onChange handler

```
struct NextPieceView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var gameEnvData: GameData
    
    @State var scene: NextPieceScene = NextPieceScene(
        size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 100))
    
    var body: some View {
        SpriteView(scene: scene)
        .onChange(of: gameEnvData.pieceCount, perform: { _ in
            scene.handleDataChange(gameEnvData: gameEnvData) })
    }
}
```